# SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: update or delete on table X violates foreign key constraint fkey on table Y

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have problem updating the display name in user table with the  following error.

**THE RELATIONSHIP**

A user can also be a supervisor. And both tables have a name field (displayName on user and name on supervisor). If a user X edit his profile and change the displayName, I want the change to reflect in the supervisor table name field. I though cascade will work but I was not getting it.

```
(node:25136) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: update or delete on table "c_user" violates foreign key constraint "c_supervisor_name_fkey" on table "c_supervisor"
```

There is a 1:n relationship between the user table and supervisor table.

**USER MODEL**

```
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    displayName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },

  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasOne(models.supervisor, { foreignKey: "userId" });
  };
    User.hasOne(models.supervisor, { foreignKey: "name" });
    
 return User;
};
```

**SUPERVISOR MODEL**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Supervisor = sequelize.define('supervisor', {
    id: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
       allowNull: false,
       primaryKey: true,
       autoIncrement: true
     },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      references: {
        model: 'c_user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'c_user',
        key: 'displayName'
      }
    },

Supervisor.associate = function(models) {
    Supervisor.belongsTo(models.user, {
      foreignKey: "userId", targetKey: "id", onDelete: "CASCADE", onUpdate: "CASCADE"
    });
    Supervisor.belongsTo(models.user, {
      foreignKey: "name", targetKey: "displayName", onDelete: "CASCADE", onUpdate: "CASCADE"
    });
  }
  
  return Supervisor;
};
```

If I update the display name in user table I want it to cascade to the name in supervisor and update it but instead I got the error above.

Comment: Why is the name relevant for the relation at all?

Comment: @Andreas the user have a profile page where they can edit their displayName. Then the same user has a name field in the supervisor model. So we want it that if the user edit there name in the user model the change should reflect immediately in the supervisor model.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Why is the name stored in two places? And why is it used in a relation? The relation is build with the id. That's it.

Comment: @Andreas In the supervisor controller I used the userId to fetch the user displayName and use it as the name. In frontend when filling the supervisor form, the user only need to specify the userId. There is no input for name it is handled in the backend. Even when I remove the name relationship and just use the userId to get the displayName, I still get the error above when I tried to update the user displayName.

Answer (score 1):

First of all using name as foreignkey is bad idea. And second if you associate two same table with each other you need to use aliases to differentiate how they related. For example:

```
// user-to-supervisor one to one relation as user
User.hasOne(Supervisor, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user'})
Supervisor.belongsTo(User)
// user-to-supervisor one to one relation as username
User.hasOne(Supervisor, {foreignKey: 'name', as: 'username'})
Supervisor.belongsTo(User)
```

Hope it will help, but what you trying to do is not practible.
Can you tell more specific about relationship you trying to achieve.

Comment: A user can also be a supervisor. And both tables have a name field (displayName on user and name on supervisor). If a user X edit his profile and change the displayName, I want the change to reflect in the supervisor table name field. I though cascade will work but I was not getting it.

Comment: @Wacademy you can build only one User model and add new field called role where can take user, supervisor.

Comment: My user model has roles already but supervisor is a separate model and not role. Thanks